# React ternary operator displays ":" block first. Why?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I have a simple react app where a current user from firebase is passed into a Header component. If the user is signed in, I want to display the "SIGN-IN" link, and if they aren't, a "SIGN OUT" link. The code works however if a user is signed in, it first displays "SIGN-IN" then switches to "SIGN OUT" rather than just only displaying "SIGN OUT". The switch is painfully obvious when first loading the page. How can I make it never display the sign in if the user is signed in?

Header:

```
const Header = ({ currentUser }) => {
    return (
        <div className="top-nav">
            <ReactSVG src={crown}/>
            <div className="links">
                <Link to="/shop">SHOP</Link>
                <Link to="/contact">CONTACT</Link>
                {
                    currentUser ? <div onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>SIGN OUT</div>
                                : <Link to="/sign-in">SIGN-IN</Link>
                }
                <Link to="/cart">CART</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Header;
```

App:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            currentUser: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            this.setState({ currentUser: user});
            console.log(user);
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        auth.signOut();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Header currentUser={this.state.currentUser}/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
                    <Route path="/sign-in" component={CredentialsPage}/>
                    <Route path="/shop" component={ShopPage}/>
                    <Route path="/shop/hats" component={Hats}/>
                    <Route path="/shop/jackets" component={Jackets}/>
                    <Route path="/shop/sneakers" component={Sneakers}/>
                    <Route path="/shop/womens" component={Womens}/>
                    <Route path="/shop/mens" component={Mens}/>
                </Switch>
            </>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both onAuthStatedChanged and setState are asynchronous.
Your initial state is currentUser: null. this is what renders first. only then, after the async calls resolves the state includes your currentUser. If you want to prevent the lag you should keep track of the state of fetching and defer the rendering of that component (maybe with an indicator or display nothing)

Answer (score 1):

You should keep a flag to check if data is received from server. isLoadComplete variable represents if data is loaded from server or not.

```
{
       isLoadComplete && {  currentUser ? <div onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>SIGN 
       OUT</div>: <Link to="/sign-in">SIGN-IN</Link>}
}
```